# Solving Basel Problem using euler infinite product and infinite product-sum equality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, taylor-expansion, infinite-product

Trying to prove Basel problem through the equality $sin(x) = x\prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{x^{2}}{\pi^{2}k^{2}})$,

I came across the following problem;

I was able to prove the following equality by induction in a finite case, I'd like to prove the general one,which is,for $\{a_{k}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ :

$$\prod_{k \in I}(1+a_{k}) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(\sum\limits_{\underset{J \in F(\mathbb{N_{+}})}{\lvert J \rvert = n}} \prod_{k \in J}a_{k})$$

Where $F(\mathbb{N_{+}})$ denotes the finite subsets on $\mathbb{N_{+}}$.

Any tip,suggestion or sketch of the proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not an infinite product rather than an infinite sum? (in your first line)

Comment: don't you mean $J \in F(\mathbb{N}_+)$?

Comment: @mrtaurho Yes, it was an oversight,thanks edited it.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes thank you,i'm gonna fix it.

Comment: Well this is obvious from the distributivity laws of products, the series on the right converges absolutely iff $\prod_k (1+|a_k|)$ converges. Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Found these slides: http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/basel-problem.pdf. Proof 1 is basically what you are looking for.

Comment: @araomis Not sure that's what i'm looking for

Comment: It is. I'll rephrase it as an answer. Note that there is a mistake in your first formula for  $sin$ as your formula does not evaluate to $0$ when you plug in $x=0$. In particular there is a factor $x$ missing.

Comment: @araomis Thanks,saw that and edited it!

Answer (score 1):

Note that I just rephrase Proof 1 from here (http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/basel-problem.pdf).

Let $iy = x/\pi$. Then we have $\sin(i\pi y) = i \pi y\Pi_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1 + y^2/k^2)$. Now let's apply logarithm on both sides to get $\log (\sin(i\pi y)) = \log(i\pi y) + \Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty}\log(1 + y^2/k^2)$. Taking the derivative with respect to $y$ on both sides yields: $$\frac{i \pi \cos(i \pi y)}{\sin(i\pi y)} = \frac{1}{y} + \Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{2y}{k^2(1 + y^2/k^2)} = \frac{1}{y} + \Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{2y}{k^2 + y^2}$$$$ \implies\Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2 + y^2} = -\frac{1}{2y^2} + \frac{i \pi \cos(i \pi y)}{2y\sin(i\pi y)}$$

So if we can find $lim_{y \rightarrow 0}RHS$ we solve the problem. Note that here I use my own derivation instead of relying to the slides mentioned above. In the following steps we use L'Hôpital's rule twice:

$$\lim_{y \rightarrow0}-\frac{1}{2y^2} + \frac{i \pi \cos(i \pi y)}{2y\sin(i\pi y)} = \lim_{y \rightarrow0}\frac{i\pi y\cos(i\pi y) - \sin(i\pi y)}{2y^2\sin(i \pi y)} \overset{BH}{=} \lim_{y \rightarrow0}\frac{i\pi \cos(i\pi y) + \pi^2 y\sin(i\pi y) - i \pi \cos(i\pi y)}{4y\sin(i \pi y) + 2i\pi y^2\cos(i\pi y)} = \lim_{y \rightarrow0}\frac{\pi^2 \sin(i\pi y)}{4\sin(i \pi y) + 2i\pi y\cos(i\pi y)} \overset{BH}{=} \lim_{y \rightarrow0}\frac{i\pi^3\cos(i\pi y)}{4i\pi \cos(i \pi y) + 2i\pi \cos(i\pi y) + 2\pi^2 y\sin(i\pi y)} = \frac{i\pi^3}{6i\pi} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$.

Comment: I see, but i don't that's the answer i'm looking for, i'd like to use the equality cited above

Comment: you could use backslash before $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\log$ to enhance readability.

Comment: @hypergeometric thanks, I'll edit that.

Comment: @jacopoburelli I start with your equation, the first thing I do is a substitution.

Comment: @araomis I understood the proof,but my question actually is not on the Basel problem rather on the equality cited above to solve it as mentioned

Comment: Oh sorry. Now I see. I totally misunderstood the question then.